# format unknown error with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webm

I'm trying to convert .webm to .mp4 using :

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i 1.webm -r 24 1.mp4
```

it doesn't work , this is what I get :

```
C:\Users\mahmoud\Desktop\ffmpeg>ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i v.webm -r 24 1.mp4
FFmpeg version SVN-r18639, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --enable-postproc --enable-gpl --enable-
libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis
--enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --disable-ffserver --enable
-avisynth --enable-pthreads
  libavutil     50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0
  libavcodec    52.27. 0 / 52.27. 0
  libavformat   52.32. 0 / 52.32. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Apr 21 2009 13:44:38, gcc: 4.2.4 (TDM-1 for MinGW)
v.webm: Unknown format
```

any one can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ffmpeg is ancient, and I believe WebM support was included later, in 2010. Get a current build from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows).

you can also try your luck with

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -f matroska -i 1.webm -r 24 1.mp4
```